# WPF/XAML DataBinding to Farthest Ancestor

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In XAML, I have a WPF user control (`DecisionTreeControl`) which represents a node in a node tree. This control creates multiple child instances of itself to represent the node's children via DataTemplate. On the lowermost node, I need a binding to refer to a `Command` on the uppermost control. Currently, I have a binding on a button on that lower-most node that looks like this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:DecisionTreeControl}}, Path=SubmitCommand}" CommandParameter={Binding}">
```

This correctly binds to the current/nearest `DecisionTreeControl`, but I need it to bind to the uppermost one in the visual tree. The controls are added via DataTemplates, so I can't just use ElementName, and the number of layers is dynamic, so I can't just set the AncestorLevel to a fixed number. The nodes also don't know how deep they are, so I can't bind to a `Depth` property.

In short, is there a way to bind (preferably via RelativeSource/FindAncestor) to a property on the uppermost instance of a type, instead of the nearest or a specific one?

If there's any other information I can add, let me know. Thank you for your time.

Comment: In case the command is in the "main" view model, i.e. the view model instance in the DataContext of the MainWindow, use `AncestorType=Window` and `Path=DataContext.SubmitCommand`.

Comment: That's a good thought, but due to restrictions on the implementation, the model originates as the DataContext in the root `DecisionTreeControl` rather than on the Window that control is placed on. This may lead to a workable, if less than convenient, solution, though.

Comment: You say that you can't use the `MemberName`, by which I am guessing you mean `ElementName` because you want to access it from within a `DataTemplate`. Why is this an issue? I have done this often, particularly where the parent provides something like a 'RemoveItemCommand' and the template for an item presents a remove button and passes itself as a command parameter.

Comment: Well, the child item is the same user control class as the parent. If I put a name on the local parent, how would it know that I want the farthest up parent, instead of its immediate parent, which would also have that relative identifier? Wouldn't each templated item also end up with the same name, since it's the same class definition?

Comment: Do your tree node models have a reference to their parent?  If so, you could add and bind to a read-only `Root` property that recursively walks the parent until it hits `null`, then returns its self.`{Binding Path=Root.SubmitCommand}`

Comment: At time of asking, my nodes did not have references to their parents, but now they do, so that will likely be the approach I take. It seems that there isn't a convenient way to do this through XAML (or more specifically `RelativeSource`), but it's good to know there's a workaround that isn't very bloated.